# What is $\mathbb{P}(V)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In context:

...Let's define "blow" (perhaps, I use incorrect terminology) of affine space $V=\mathbb{A}^n$ in point $P=(0,\ldots,0)$. Consider subset
$$\widetilde{V}=\{(v, L)|v\in L\}\subset V\times \mathbb{P}(V),$$
and define projection $\sigma : \widetilde{V}\to V~~$ as $(v, L)\longmapsto v$.  ...

So, What is $\mathbb{P}(V)$?

Thanks.

Comment: It's called a ‘blowup’. $\mathbb{P}(V)$ is the projective $(n-1)$-space obtained by considering the $1$-dimensional subspaces of $V$, considered as a vector space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to construct a [blow up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up). Here $\mathbf P(V)$ is the [projective space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space) of lines through the origin in the vector space $V$. You can give this the structure of a variety by choosing a basis (and it seems like you already have), which will give you an isomorphism of $\mathbf{P}(V)$ with some $\mathbf{P}^{n - 1}$.

There are many things to learn about this last space. To begin with, the closed sets in $\mathbf{P}^n$ are the zero sets of collections of homogeneous polynomials. What sort of functions will be attached to these sets? How do these sets relate to varieties in $\mathbf{A}^n$? What is that [product operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding)? This should all be explained in any textbook on basic algebraic geometry. There are some nice pictures in [Harris's book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Algebraic_geometry.html?id=_XxZdhbtf1sC), for example.

Comment: Am I right that $\dim L=1$ and $L$ generated by $v$?

Comment: @Aspirin That seems right.